# Invoke a function when a model value is changed on Angular 4

Tags: angular, design-patterns, observable

I am working on angular 4 project.

I have filter object `globalFilter` and method `filterByClient`

```
filterByClient(obj) {
    this.globalFilter['client__uuid'] = obj.uuid;
    this.serviceCall(this.globalFilter); // Http service call 
}
```

When I click on a button `filterByClient(obj)` is invoked and http service is called. This is working solution.

Now I want the more robust solution. When I change anything on `this.globalFilter` automatically Http service will be called.

I am sure we can solve it by Observer pattern. But I am here to get community hands.

Comment: What's the *type* of `this.globalFilter`?

Comment: @NishantShreshth that will be a mutable object. May have nested object but for now depth 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your object in a `Subject`:

```js
globalFilterSource = new Subject<any>();
globalFilter$ = globalFilterSource.asObservable();

// handle filter update
globalFilter$.subscribe(
  newGlobalFilter => {
    // filter updated
  }
)

// notify filter update from elsewhere
globalFilterSource.next(newGlobalFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use rxjs is the best way to reactive this behaviour.
I suggest the solution bellow:

1. First set a globalFilter behaviour object.

   globalFilter: BehaviourObject = new BehaviourObject( new Client() );
2. Subscribe to the object to call automatically the http call when client data change:

   globalFilter.subscribe(client => this.serviceCall(client); );
3. Emet an event when client data change:

   Client.uuid = object.uuid

   globalFilter.next(client);